# How to replicate and sync MongoDB localhost to a remote server using replica set

Tags: mongodb, remote-server, mongodb-replica-set

**Initially I started two node(primary and secondary)  on same host machine on two different port , secondary  was secondary was correctly replicating primary , but my actual requirement is on two different machine with two diff IP address , one should act as Primary other one should act as secondary ,To do that I remove secondary in my local host , and see status below , then tried to add remote IP on same replica , But showing error described below , please help.**

```
    "members" : [
            {
                "_id" : 0,
                "name" : "localhost:27017",
                "health" : 1,
                "state" : 1,
                "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                "uptime" : 5359,
                "optime" : {
                    "ts" : Timestamp(1502370582, 1),
                    "t" : NumberLong(1)
                },
                "optimeDate" : ISODate("2017-08-10T13:09:42Z"),
                "electionTime" : Timestamp(1502366671, 1),
                "electionDate" : ISODate("2017-08-10T12:04:31Z"),
                "configVersion" : 4,
                "self" : true
            }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
    }

myreplset:PRIMARY> config = {_id:"myreplset", members:[          {_id:0, host:"localhost:27017"},          {_id:1, host:"192.168.205.59:27017"} ]          };
    {
        "_id" : "myreplset",
        "members" : [
            {
                "_id" : 0,
                "host" : "localhost:27017"
            },
            {
                "_id" : 1,
                "host" : "192.168.205.59:27017"
            }
        ]
    }
    myreplset:PRIMARY> rs.initiate(config);
    {
        "info" : "try querying local.system.replset to see current configuration",
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "already initialized",
        "code" : 23,
        "codeName" : "AlreadyInitialized"
    }
```

Comment: myreplset:PRIMARY> rs.add("192.168.205.59:27017");
{
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "Either all host names in a replica set configuration must be localhost references, or none must be; found 1 out of 2",
 "code" : 103,
 "codeName" : "NewReplicaSetConfigurationIncompatible"
}

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is the site to use for database administration and configuration questions. StackOverflow is for programming topics only, of which this question is not. **Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting.**